# Trying to get rid of a column in a matplotlib graph

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

We have this code that came with motion capture software from Vicon Nexus. Using Python, we generate graphs captured from an EMG analog source. 
The included Amplitude vs Frequency column is extraneous. We are able to comment out the section of the code that fills in the the second column, but it still leaves the empty subplots in column 2.

```
def plot(axrow, ax, ay, alim, bx, by, blim, emgLabel):
    axrow[0].plot(ax, ay, color='blue', label=emgLabel)
    axrow[0].set_xlim(alim)
    axrow[0].set_xlabel('Time / s')
    axrow[0].set_ylabel('Volt. / V', fontsize=9)
    axrow[0].legend()
    axrow[0].locator_params(axis='y', nbins=3)
    #axrow[1].plot(bx, by, color='red', label=emgLabel)
    #axrow[1].set_xlim(blim)
    #axrow[1].set_xlabel('Frequency / Hz')
    #axrow[1].set_ylabel('Ampl./ a.u.', fontsize=9)
    #axrow[1].legend()
    #axrow[1].locator_params(axis='y', nbins=3)
```

[Second Column Empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTu2C.png)

When we change the argument for subplots from 2 to 1, only one column appears but the plots are completely empty

```
nrows = len(channelId)
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows, 1)
```

[One Column, No Graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smKXw.png)

There are 8 channelIDs

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Edit: Sorry for the delayed response. We were able to finally figure out the solution by using "squeeze=false".

Here is the entirity fo the code for clarity

```
from __future__ import division, print_function

import ViconNexus
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import butter, lfilter


# define butterworth bandpass filter
def butter_bandpass(lowcut, highcut, fs, order=5):
    nyq = 0.5 * fs
    low = lowcut / nyq
    high = highcut / nyq
    b, a = butter(order, [low, high], btype='band')
    return b, a


def butter_bandpass_filter(data, lowcut, highcut, fs, order=5):
    b, a = butter_bandpass(lowcut, highcut, fs, order=order)
    y = lfilter(b, a, data)
    return y

   #plot(row, timeLineCut, x, alim, freq, np.abs(y), blim, emgLabel)
def plot(axrow, ax, ay, alim, bx, by, blim, emgLabel):
    axrow[0].plot(ax, ay, color='blue', label=emgLabel)
    axrow[0].set_xlim(alim)
    axrow[0].set_xlabel('Time / s')
    axrow[0].set_ylabel('Volt. / V', fontsize=9)
    axrow[0].legend()
    axrow[0].locator_params(axis='y', nbins=3)
    #axrow[1].plot(bx, by, color='red', label=emgLabel)
    #axrow[1].set_xlim(blim)
    #axrow[1].set_xlabel('Frequency / Hz')
    #axrow[1].set_ylabel('Ampl./ a.u.', fontsize=9)
    #axrow[1].legend()
    #axrow[1].locator_params(axis='y', nbins=3)  


vicon = ViconNexus.ViconNexus()

# Extract information from active trial
subjectName = vicon.GetSubjectNames()[0]
sessionLoc = vicon.GetTrialName()[0]
trialName = vicon.GetTrialName()[1]


analogId = 3
emgOutId = 1

channelNames = vicon.GetDeviceOutputDetails(3, 1)[4]
channelId = vicon.GetDeviceOutputDetails(3, 1)[5]


nrows = 4
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows, 1, squeeze=False)


# over all analog channels
for ii, row in zip(range(nrows), axes):

    emgId = channelId[ii]
    emgData = vicon.GetDeviceChannel(analogId, emgOutId, emgId)[0]
    emgDataRate = vicon.GetDeviceChannel(analogId, emgOutId, emgId)[2]
    emgDataArray = np.asarray(emgData)
    timeLine = np.arange(emgDataArray.size)

    # write routine to select Left / right from trial_name

    if channelNames[ii][-1] == 'R':
        testEvent = vicon.GetEvents(subjectName, 'Right', 'Foot Strike')
        testEventOff = vicon.GetEvents(subjectName, 'Right', 'Foot Off')
    else:
        testEvent = vicon.GetEvents(subjectName, 'Left', 'Foot Strike')
        testEventOff = vicon.GetEvents(subjectName, 'Left', 'Foot Off')

    trajDataRate = vicon.GetFrameRate()

    if len(testEventOff[0]) == 1:
        startFrameTraj = testEvent[0][0]
        footOffFrame = testEventOff[0][0]
        stopFrameTraj = testEvent[0][1]
    else:
        startFrameTraj = testEvent[0][0]
        footOffFrame = testEventOff[0][1]
        stopFrameTraj = testEvent[0][1]


    startFrameAnal = int(startFrameTraj * (emgDataRate/trajDataRate))
    footOffAnal = int(footOffFrame * (emgDataRate/trajDataRate))
    stopFrameAnal = int(stopFrameTraj * (emgDataRate/trajDataRate))

    emgDataCut = emgDataArray[startFrameAnal:stopFrameAnal]
    T = 1.0 / 4000.0  # time per frame
    tEnd = T * (emgDataCut.size - 1)
    timeLineCut = np.linspace(0.0, tEnd, num=emgDataCut.size)
    #timeLineCut = np.arange(emgDataCut.size)

    # do some filtering
    fs = emgDataRate  # sample rate
    lowCut = 40.0  # Hz
    highCut = 800.0  # Hz
    order = 6  # or 2, 4 ...?
    x = butter_bandpass_filter(emgDataCut, lowCut, highCut, fs, order)

    # another style for fft
    Y = emgDataCut
    y = np.fft.fft(Y)
    freq = np.fft.fftfreq(len(Y), T)

    alim = [0, tEnd+1]
    blim = [0, 600]
    emgLabel = channelNames[ii]
    plot(row, timeLineCut, x, alim, freq, np.abs(y), blim, emgLabel)

fig.suptitle('EMG and spectrum - %s - %s' % (subjectName, trialName))
fig.set_size_inches(6, 10)  # for landscape
fig.savefig('%s%s_%s_EMG.pdf' % (sessionLoc, subjectName, trialName))
```

Comment: Please read [mcve]. I.e. we need a complete example to see what's happening here.

Comment: I think that the axrow variable get's messed up by reducing the number of figures, but without more code I can only guess. P.s. could you fix the indentation?

Comment: @YerevanMotion Those comments are meant for you to [edit] your question accordingly. If you ignore them that will not bring you closer to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to you use "squeeze=False" in the subplots argument and switch the number of colmuns to 1

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows, 1, squeeze=False)
```